# HTML in a column value, how to remove it?

Tags: development, asp.net

I use this code to load data from content list to grid view.

```
private void Data_load()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();


            string currentName = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Name;
            SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
            query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Editor'/><Value Type='Person or Group'>" + currentName + "</Value></Eq></Where>";

            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://spdev-6/"))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList lists = web.GetList("Lists/Advertisements");

                    SPListItemCollection items = lists.GetItems(query);
                    if (items.Count > 0)
                    {
                        dt = items.GetDataTable();

                    }
                    else
                        lbldata.Text = "No data to show";



                    GridViewD.DataSource = dt;
                    GridViewD.DataBind();
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["Advertisement"] = dt;


                }
            }
```

Now the problem is I am having grid-view in  thefollowing way.

```
120 test solution   <div class="ExternalClassF4E196F98B854967967940C30034C946"><p>ghdsjflkhgdfjklag​</p></div>  22552
```

I have to remove the div and Html from this column.

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate your question and mention clearly what issue are you facing.

Comment: Please check the description column in  image i have share

Comment: What value are you expecting to be present in description column? is it only `ghdsjflkhgdfjklag`?

Comment: Yes i am expecting it only in description not the html

Comment: Disable the HTML render in the wanted column `<asp:BoundField DataField="MyColumn" HtmlEncode="false" />`

Comment: will you please put it in answer so i can mark it as answer ?

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Yes, successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try disabling `HtmlEncode`.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Your Column Name" HtmlEncode="false" />
```

`BoundField.HtmlEncode` Property in [*MSDN*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.htmlencode(v=vs.110).aspx)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27720086/1294606

Comment: Please mention the source from where you got this. I believe it is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27719898/how-to-remove-html-tags-from-the-gridview-row

Answer (score 2):

Use can use `HtmlDecode` for it.

eg:

In RowDataBound event use

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    string decodedText = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(e.Row.Cells[0].Text);
    e.Row.Cells[0].Text = decodedText;
}
```

Comment: How to do it on item collection ?

Comment: You are using a gridview right. you can format in rowdatabound event. Is there any specific reason you are looking the same functionality in at item collection level?

Comment: At datatable or after assigning datatable as datasource of gridview

Comment: I am thinking to put it in if condition where putting items in datatable.

Comment: This (rowdataBound) is event associated with gridview. you have to write the logic in this event.

Comment: I am not binding it row by row i am doing it this way            GridViewD.DataSource = dt;                    GridViewD.DataBind();